# Prestashop 1.7 show category only to admin

Tags: prestashop, admin, categories, preview, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to find a way to preview a category page on PS 1.7 only to admin. I want to hide it from users in the menu and via the URL but be able to preview it as I'm connected as an admin.

Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: This is not really a coding question. But you can create a customer group, and a customer for you to test. Then edit the category to restrict only to the created group.

Comment: Oh right thank you. I didn't think before asking it here. But good idea thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to create a customer group "TEST" and assign you a customer account in this group, as well as assign the customer group to the category.

So only you will see the category.